# how to query over a list of numbers in line

Tags: c#, linq

This is such a simple question, but I cannot find the answer.

What I am looking for is the lightweight way of enumerating through a list of integers without having to define a new array or list or something. The code shown below represents what I want to do, but it doesn't work.

```
var x = from z in [] {1, 19, 64, 128, 132}
  select new {z, "asdffdghdfgh" };
```

The bit I need help with, without creating something horrible or another variable, is the `{1, 19, .... }` inline

Thanks

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do so you must still instantiate an array. This still allocates the object but you just don't have any reference to it after the query is executed.

```
// See addition of `new int[]`
var x = from z in new int[] { 1, 19, 64, 128, 132 } 
        select new { z, x = "someText" };
```

If you were creating a `string[]` then you wouldn't have to specify the string word before the `[]` but you would still have to write `new [] {...}`